# Using Form Wizard with pages that have no forms

Tags: django

I am working on a Django project where I have about 7 pages all in order. Basically step 1 - 7. I would like for them to have some sort of navigation/progress bar above the content showing where they are in the pages and how much they have completed. The only thing I have found close to this is using Wizard Form. The only issue I run into with this is some pages do not have a form.

```
Page 1 = Pure text explaining information
Page 2 = Setup information
Page 3 = Form
Page 4 = Form
Page 5 = Information
Page 6 = Form
Page 7 = Completion/Thanks
```

Is  it possible to still use the Wizard Form for this setup? Or is there a better method of doing what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Wizard form, but they look decent. Here are a few things you can try:

The first way is complicated. From my experience, React libraries like Material-UI have support for a navigation bar, progress bar, and all sorts of transition effects. They are complicated to get started though, and I won't advise you to try this unless you had worked with React before.

The second way is sort of a cheat. If Wizard Form requires a form on every single page, you can use something like this to easily get by:

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
  <p>Put whatever you want here. Divs, text, whatever.</p>
</form>
```

As you might've noticed, it's a form with GET request with no actions and a submit button. In that sense, you can just treat this form as a regular division. If Wizard Forms requires just a form, you should get by with this trick.